# Where can I get a MiFi device?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, mifi

I'm looking into getting a MiFi device. Where can I purchase one?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): `it is not about` **a shopping or buying recommendation**

Comment: Edited - I don't know where to buy one at all. Just looking for sellers, not recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Novatel-Wireless-MiFi-2372-Unlocked/dp/B0039ZLMK0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039ZLMK0)

Comment: Amazon is an obvious place I missed.